Will Windows Modules Installer Worker finish cleanup task started by DISM if console window was closed?
I have started cleanup of nearly 30 Gb WinSxS folder on old notebook running Windows 10 2016 LTSB (it gets security updates so far) by issuing command "Dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup" in cmd, and some hours later accidentally closed console window at around 70% of reported progress. The Windows Modules Installer Worker process is still running. Will it complete cleanup without Dism? Is there a way to see how much work has to be done yet?

“Will it complete cleanup without Dism?” - no

I would watch the folder sizes via a command script or refreshing folder properties for a little while, and also watch the Windows Module Installer process in task manager. If things are not changing at all, you may want to reopen the command prompt and run the command again, but if things are changing (even slowly, as in over a few hours) leave them be.

Well, it was doing something, loading CPU, writing to cbs.log. I have tried to open new cmd window and issue the same command again. It wasn't showing progress bar at first, but couple of hours later noise from the cooling fan has become more quiet. I looked on the screen, and there was progress bar showing 20% and message that command was completed successfully. Now WinSxS is smaller by 20 Gb.
